# Map groupBy with multi-sort

Tags: scala, dictionary, group-by, sorting

Going a bit nutty here trying to multi-sort on the following.

```
case class WeeklyResults(
  schedule: Schedule,
  result: GameResult
)
val games = // returns correctly sorted List of WeeklyResults
  repo.gameresult.findAllByDate(date)
```

Things go awry when I groupBy on game date (to display game date header per game day) and id (to group home/away team pairs) as an unsorted map is returned, fun ;-)

```
val unsorted = // Map[JodaTime, Iterable[List[WeeklyResults]]]
  games.groupBy(_.schedule.gameDate).mapValues(_.groupBy(_.schedule.id).values)
```

Ok, well, ListMap is one way to get a sorted map, let's try that, sorting on game date JodaTime in milliseconds.

```
val sorted =
  ListMap(unsorted.toList.sortBy(_._1.getMillis):_*)
```

All good, games are sorted under game date headers in correct order...but, the games within each game day are sorted at random ;-(

So, the question is, how on earth can I sort *both by game date and game result id*? (where id is PK of game results table, effectively the sort order at DB level)

I have tried various combinations of futility:

```
unsorted.flatMap{x=>
  ListMap(
    Seq( (x._1, x._2.map(_._2.sortBy(_.result.id))) ).sortBy(_.1.getMillis)
  :_*)
}
```

No matter what I do, the `Iterable[List[WeeklyResults]]` remains unsorted

Ideas greatly appreciated, am at my wits end, entire morning gone on this

Answer (score 2):

I think the key problem is that your groupBy inside a groupBy returns a complex type (Iterable over List).

If I simplify that part using 'flatten', things become much simpler. I've used a dumbed-down version of your case class

```
case class WeeklyResults(
  schedule: DateTime,
  id: Int
)
```

and then used the following:

```
val unsorted = // Map[JodaTime, List[WeeklyResults]]
    games.groupBy(_.schedule).mapValues(_.groupBy(_.id).values.flatten.toList)
```

sorted just like you did (cool trick with the ListMap, by the way):

```
val sorted = //ListMap[DateTime, List[WeeklyResults] ]
    ListMap(unsorted.toList.sortBy(_._1.getMillis):_*)
```

and then the secondary sort is just:

```
val reallySorted = sorted.mapValues( v => v.sortBy( _.id) )
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: +1, that's right the Iterable[List[T]] is the bugger in terms of sorting. I need to test your solution to see if it works ;-)

Comment: too bad, doesn't work, or at least not on first try.  I think the Iterable[List[T]] created by groupBy on game result id allows for me to map through game results as List(a,b) pairs. When I flatten as you suggest, it seems the pairing is gone; as a result a match error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This is heinously bad, but not sure how else to approach the problem without restructuring the model.

So, I pass in the semi-sorted ListMap (i.e. sorted on game date) to the view:

```
@(model: Map[org.joda.time.DateTime, Iterable[List[ushr.model.WeeklyResults]]])

@model.map{ case(date,games) =>
  // display game date headers
  ...

  // the ugliness ensues
  @games.toSeq.map(x=>x).sortBy(_(0).result.id).map{ case(List(a,b))=>
    // display game results on this particular game date
    ...
  }
}
```

Basically, since each gameresult is a List'd pair, I sort on the first game result id in the pair (could do on the 2nd just as well, same game id, different game result/outcome for each team).

This works, but is really painful given that the original database query returns the result set in desired order. Spent about 3 hours hashing through this, interesting but...a total waste of the little time I have available right now.  Would ABSOLUTELY LOVE a groupBy that preserved collection order.

If someone has a "real" solution vs. the hacked one I've come up with, please do chime in...